# Alternatives to flyspell-mode for emacs

Tags: emacs, flyspell

I just started with emacs and I wanted to know if there is a an alternative for flyspell for checking spellings in comments (Since I use auto-complete-mode for code completion, I can't have flyspell minor mode on as they conflict with each rendering auto-complete-mode useless).

Thanks

Comment: I just flip it on and off but it should be possible to add a constant to flyspell and keep track of whether you in or outside comments. To lazy to implement it but hope for an answer

Comment: that would be flyspell-prog-mode which only checks in comments. But even flyspell-prog-mode auto-complete does not work :(

Comment: found a workaround after searching in the forums. Just enter `(ac-flyspell-workaround)`  and we are good to go :) auto-complete works with flyspell.

Comment: I don't use auto-complete, but you can just add a flyspell on/off at the outset and tail end of the completion function.  No need to look for an alternative to flyspell.  If you can point to the particular completion function at issue so I or someone else can Google it to see the source code, an answer should be easy for anyone of us to write up.

Comment: This works for me also, thanks. Emacs rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround after searching the forums.
We just have to enter this

`(ac-flyspell-workaround)`

and it would work like a charm.

Cheers